# how to update a mysql table using statement update from?

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, mysql-workbench

i need to update the enrollment table with the appropriate fee which comes from the course table for all customer taking the course named 'COURSE NAME'

```
update from enrollment as e
    join course as c on c.coursenumber = e.coursenumber
    join customer as cs on cs.customernumber = e.customernumber 
set e.amountpaid = course.fee
where e.coursenumber in (select coursenumber from course where course = 'COURSE   NAME');
```

Is that possible in mysql ? I'm new to this DBMS and sql in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove the `FROM` keyword.

```
update enrollment as e
    join course as c on c.coursenumber = e.coursenumber
    join customer as cs on cs.customernumber = e.customernumber 
set e.amountpaid = course.fee
where e.coursenumber in (select coursenumber from course where course = 'COURSE   NAME');
```

or just directly do without `IN`

```
update enrollment as e
    join course as c on c.coursenumber = e.coursenumber
    join customer as cs on cs.customernumber = e.customernumber 
set e.amountpaid = course.fee
where  c.course = 'COURSE   NAME';
```